# bool.fromEnvironment always return false

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's a code:

```
const bool a = const bool.fromEnvironment("true");
print(a); // false
```

Yes, default value is false by default. What should I do that `a` will be true, without using default value? And what is the string parameter? is it a key maybe?

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `fromEnvironment()` if you are not sure about `fromEnvironment` parameter?

Comment: I'm just checking all classes, functions, etc in dart lang.. and in bool class I found bool.fromEnvironment and there was written 'Returns the boolean value of the environment declaration name. The boolean value of the declaration is true if the declared value is the string "true", and false if the value is "false".'

Comment: but result is always false.. whatever I wrote in fromEnvironment parameter

Comment: I always get false when I do debugging. I think because it's a compile time arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? 
Setting `a` to true can be done as `const a = true;`.

The `bool.fromEnvironment` function allows you to look up defined named string properties that can be added at the command line when compiling, or which may be defined by the platform you are compile for/running on. So does `String.fromEnvironment` and `int.fromEnvironment`.

One set of such platform properties are `dart.library.*` which are set to `true` for each `dart:*` library that the platform supports.

So, to print something other than `false`, you can do:

```
print(const bool.fromEnvironment("dart.library.core"));
```

That one is pretty boring since all platforms support `dart:core`.
You can check the availability of other libraries as:

```
const bool supportsMirrors = bool.fromEnvironment("dart.library.mirrors");
const bool isJavaScript = bool.fromEnvironment("dart.library.js");
```

Or, you can supply a value on the command line when compiling. Let's use the `dart` stand-alone VM as an example. Write the following script `script.dart`:

```
void main() {
  print(const bool.fromEnvironment("my-fancy-thing"));
}
```

If you run it as `dart script.dart` it prints `false`.
If you run it as `dart -Dmy-fancy-thing=true script.dart` it prints `true`.

Comment: wow, thanks .. even in thoughts there wasn’t what was meant by the libraries, etc.